# What happens to postdoc applications when they've been received? (US)

Tags: united-states, postdocs, early-career

On the internet I found that some universities list their committees. For instance, the postdoc hiring committee might have two faculty members. What is their role? Are they the only people who read the applications? Is everyone in the department involved in postdoc hiring or is it just a few faculty members? I'm mainly referring to positions in the United States. **Who is involved in postdoc hiring and how are the applications processed?**

Also, a lot of job applications say that they prefer to pick somebody whose research interests align with those in the department. How much does that matter? I also am thinking that maybe I should cold e-mail potential postdoc mentors in the department to let them know I exist and to express interest in their department. **How do I demonstrate in my application that I belong in their department?**

My understanding is that they have to narrow down the list of applicants to a "short list," and I'm wondering how that is done. Then they have to rank the applicants and then go down the list until they get enough applicants to accept their offer. **How do they make the short list?**

Comment: Very dependent on the institution or department.

Comment: In particular, this will depend on whether postdocs are hired by the department or by the individual PIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several models of postdoc hiring (in the US, assuming the hiring is by the department rather than by individual PIs). In all of this, random factors play major role. My examples and suggestions are in math (which is what you are interested in, I think.)

Model 1. There is a postdoc hiring committee of, say, 3 people. The committee solicits names for making a "long list" from the rest of the departmental members. If nobody volunteers to mentor an applicant X, then X will not make it to the "long list," no matter how many "Annals" papers they published. Then the committee meets in order to make a short list. Suppose that this year the department has two postdoctoral positions to fill and members A and B of the committee are both interested in mentoring a postdoc. They meet somewhere over a coffee and propose that the offers go to Y and Z (top of the lists of A and B respectively). The third member of the committee, C, is outvoted, and Y and Z are hired. Mission accomplished!

Model 2. Say, there are 5 members of the hiring committee and there are 3 postdoctoral positions to be filled. After getting a feedback from the faculty, the committee meets to make their "short list." There are quite a few arguments based on parameters such as gender, ethnicity, who had a postdoc recently, whose CV is most impressive... The arguments last for, oh well, 5 hours since applicants in PDEs are compared to applicants in Number Theory. In the end, after making increasingly narrow lists, the committee comes up with a ranked list of 6 applicants: 3 will get offers, 3 more are alternates in case some offers are declined.

Lastly, to your question: "How do I demonstrate in my application that I belong in their department?" My only suggestion is to ensure that your research interacts with the research of some faculty at the department, otherwise you will not make it to a "long list." In particular, go to conferences, give seminar talks, meet people in your area of math, talk to them, etc. Make your research statement potentially "interesting," including a list of open problems you would like to pursue.

Comment: It does seem like there is a lot of randomness involved. At one place where I applied nobody in my field or even adjacent field got an offer. The applicants who were offered positions worked in a completely different area. Myabe it was time for the PDE faculty member to get a postdoc.

Comment: @cgb5436: That's right.  Similar randomness (plus some "horse-trading") one observes at the tenure-track level hires.

Comment: One way of putting this is that it's not "intrinsic virtue" that gets jobs, but virtue+fit. Which is reasonable, for most models of hiring/admission.

Comment: @paulgarrett: virtue+fit+politics

Comment: @MoisheKohan, ah, well, indeed :) Though "politics" does start to sound like an inappropriate criterion... Still, yes, I agree, and "politics" can be manifest in ways that smart people, such as academics, can dress up as something less subjective, etc.

Comment: @paulgarrett: politics is probably inevitable.

Comment: @MoisheKohan :)  "Upon prolonged observation, I think you're right." :) Though/and perhaps the more explanatory description is something about "power", or similar. ... or, maybe, I'm just "late to the party" of understanding that myself!?! :)

Comment: What my PhD advisor told me was that the reason he got a job was because out of all the people who applied there, he was the best.

Comment: @cgb5436: Who knows, maybe your advisor was right about that particular place and particular time. What I observed in 30+ years at two different departments is roughly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @cgb5436, good... but/and if only we knew what "best" is/was. It's surely not a "scalar"... Perhaps one way of describing hiring/admissions, all this stuff, is that "merit/virtues" is not a scalar, to begin with. We don't get jobs purely on "virtue", in any case, even if we declare that "math virtue" is a scalar, etc.